# Output a record from an existing file based on a matching condition in bash scripting

Tags: shell

I need to be able to output a record if a condition is true.

Suppose this is the existing file,

Record_ID,Name,Last Name,Phone Number

I am trying to output record if the last name matches.  I collect user input to get last name and then perform the following operation.

```
read last_name
cat contact_records.txt | awk -F, '{if($3=='$last_name')print "match"; else print "no match";}'
```

This script outputs no match for every record within contact_records.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has two problems:

First, $last_name is not considered quoted in the context of 'awk'.  For example, if "John" is to be queried, you are comparing $3 with the variable John rather than string "John".  This can be fixed by adding two double-quotes as below:

```
read last_name
cat contact_records.txt | awk -F, '{if($3=="'$last_name'")print "match"; else print "no match";}'
```

Second, it actually scans the whole contact_records.txt and prints match/no match for each line of comparison.  For example,  contact_records.txt has 100 lines, with "John" in it. Then, querying if John is in it by this script yields 1 "match"'s and 99 "no match"'s.  This might not be what you want.  Here's a fix:

```
read last_name
if [ `cat contact_records.txt | cut -d, -f 3 | grep -c "$last_name"` -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "no match"
else
  echo "match"
fi
```

Comment: In fact, expanding shell variables as part of awk's command line is dangerous.  Please follow [this link](http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24) for detail.